# updating a column with a condition from another table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

So basically I need to update a column to return true whenever there's a feature from another table nearby

my query so far looks like

```
update tablea a set is_nearby = 
case when b.condition1 = 1 and st_dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 100) then true
else false end
from tableb b
```

But this just returns everything false when I know that's not the case

Comment: Please post sample data with expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `exists`:

```
update tablea a
    set is_nearby = (case when exists (select 1
                                       from tableb b
                                       where b.condition1 = 1 and st_dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 100)
                          then true
                          else false
                      end);
```

Or more simply without the `case`:

```
update tablea a
    set is_nearby = (exists (select 1
                             from tableb b
                             where b.condition1 = 1 and st_dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 100)
                    );
```

The problem with your query is that the `from` is generating a cross product, so all rows from `b` are being compared to each row from `a`.  However, only one value is getting set -- and that value comes from an arbitrary matching row in `b`.